# Oozie 4.0.0 build error - could not resolve hcatalog dependencies

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hcatalog

Hadoop version-1.2.1

Maven version - 3.0.5

hive version - 0.14.0

pig version - 0.14.0

When i started building oozie with below command

./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests

i get below error

```
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:13.847s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 09 13:22:12 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/273M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hcatalog:jar:0.5.0.oozie-4.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:webhcat-java-client:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:0.14.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.14.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:0.14.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-serde:jar:0.14.0 (compile), org.apache.thrift:libfb303:jar:0.7.0 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:jar:0.14.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:pom:0.14.0 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
```

With the error it seems that it is not able to resolve the dependencies on hcatalog. But since i am using hive-0.14 in which hcatalog is built inside hive, is there a way to exclude hcatalog dependency. Or the error implies something else how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by disabling the dependency on repository.codehaus.org as the repo is not available after may. And the other dependencies are got from the maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

*"hcatalog is built inside hive"*

Not exactly true: HCatalog allows any application (Pig, Spark, Sqoop, etc) to access the Hive Metastore; it's usually bundled with Hive install kit, but it can be extracted and used w/o the rest of Hive libs.

And indeed, Oozie bundles two different ShareLibs for Hive (default for Hive action) and HCatalog (additional - and optional - ShareLib for Pig/Spark/Sqoop action requiring access to Hive tables).

Comment: Agree Thanks. I fixed this by disabling the dependency on repository.codehaus.org as the repo is not available after may and the other dependencies are got from the maven repository.